# rsync: delete except on one folder

Tags: rsync

I have a tree that is like this: `/home/me/A/secret/`. I'd like to sync (recursively) the folder `/home/me/A/` (including the subfolder `secret`), in the folder `/opt` of the destination. Moreover, I also would like to delete the files that are in the source but not in the destination, **except** if the files belong to the `secret` folder.

Indeed, the `secret` folder won't be always present on the machine, and I don't want to remove the `secret` folder on the remote server when it's the case.

What I tried: the option `--delete` deletes everything, so I tried `--delete --exclude secret/`, but the problem is that it won't even sync the content of `secret/`. Then, `--filter "protect ..."` requires a file with all the files that I want to protect, which is really not practical.

So for now the best option I found is to run two instances of rsync: one with `--exclude secret/ --delete` to deal with everything except the `secret` folder, and then I run another rsync to sync directly the subfolder `secret` to the good position.

Is there a `one-command` way to do that?

Thanks!